# Moving Bootstrap sidebar

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Lets define the following layout using bootstrap:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div onclick="smallSize()">Click</div>
    <div onclick="largeSize()">Click</div>

    <div class="row">

        <!--Video player-->
        <div class="video-player-content col-7" style="max-width:720px;">
            <video id="preview" width="720px" height="360px">
                <source/>
            </video>
        </div>

        <!--Sidebar content-->
        <div class="sidebar-card col-5">
            <p>Some content</p>
        </div>  

    </div>

</div>
```

I have 2 icons for changing the size of the video player, kind of youtube like feature.
Clicking on them changes the size of the video player, I use JQuery to achieve this.

```
function smallSize() {
    var video = document.getElementById("preview");
    video.height = 360;
    video.width = 720;
    document.getElementsByClassName("video-player-content")[0].style.maxWidth = "720";
}

function largeSize() {
    var video = document.getElementById("preview");
    video.height = 540;
    video.width = 1080;
    document.getElementsByClassName("video-player-content")[0].style.maxWidth = "1080";
}
```

My problem is, when changing to the large player, the video player col overflows (actually underflows) the sidebar.
How can I push the sidebar below the video player if the user chooses to watch the video on the larger player?
I tried to play around with col-sm-md-lg and also tried the clearfix, but no success.
Defining the maxwidth attribute is important, as there there is also a canvas on top of the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I realized classes can be added and removed with jQuery,so I used the following methods in both of my onClick functions

```
$("<id of element>").removeClass("<class to be removed>");
$("<id of element>").addClass("<class to be added>");
```